# Is post request for saving user necessary when using Prisma Adapter in NextAuth?

Tags: next.js, prisma, next-auth

I'm making an application using Next.js + NextAuth.js + Prisma + MongoDB.
I'm trying to save the user's info on DB when a new user attempts to login with OAuth.
I've found out that when using Prisma Adapter as an adapter in `[...nextauth].ts`  and PrismaAdapter has already built-in codes such as creating user in database as below:

```
// node_modules/@next-auth/prisma-adapter/dist/index.js

function PrismaAdapter(p) {
 return {
 createUser: (data) => p.user.create({ data }),
 getUser: (id) => p.user.findUnique({ where: { id } }),
 getUserByEmail: (email) => p.user.findUnique({ where: { email } }),
 async getUserByAccount(provider_providerAccountId) {
 var _a;
 const account = await p.account.findUnique({
 where: { provider_providerAccountId },
 select: { user: true },
 });
 return (_a = account === null || account === void 0 ? void 0 : account.user) !== null && _a !== void 0 ? _a : null;
 },
 updateUser: ({ id, ...data }) => p.user.update({ where: { id }, data }),
 deleteUser: (id) => p.user.delete({ where: { id } }),
 linkAccount: (data) => p.account.create({ data }),
 unlinkAccount: (provider_providerAccountId) => p.account.delete({
 where: { provider_providerAccountId },
 }),
```

But I've noticed that many people are writing redundant code within their project directories to create a new user as below: (I've got the code from [here](https://github.com/HamedBahram/nextjs-13/blob/1edd7139d6c94fe814108666488dd0e7c7cd77ee/lib/prisma/users.js#L12))

```
export async function createUser(user) { 
  try { 
    const userFromDB = await prisma.user.create({ data: user }) 
    return { user: userFromDB } 
  } catch (error) { 
    return { error } 
  }
}
```

I'm new to Next.js, NextAuth, and Prisma, so it seems to me that this code is unnecessary since Prisma Adapter itself already has the same code doing the same thing.
Is there other reason doing this?
Thanks in advance.